# Show ajax process 1 by 1 when something is done

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a code and it works, and it shows all notifications at the same time.

I have question..

How to get notifications when one of the functions is done? (Notifications appear one by one)

---

There are several functions in the `indexing.php` file.

```
$preproses = $_POST["preproses"];
if($preproses == "preproses"){
    //mulai proses
    set_time_limit(0);
    buatindex();
    hitungbobot();
    panjangvektor();
}

function buatindex() {
    code
}

function hitungbobot() {
    code
}

function panjangvektor() {
    code
}
```

---

In `index.php` there is a code to call that function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function preproses(){

      var preprosesx = "preproses";
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "indexing.php",
        data: {preproses:preprosesx},
        error: function(){
        $("#notif").prepend("fail");
        },
        success: function(html){
        $("#notif").prepend("Process done <br/>"+html);
        },
      });
      return false;
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="preproses()">click to precess</a>
```

If all processes are completed, a notification will appear

```
<span id="notif"></span>
```

Comment: You have written a ajax call , call that in particular time interavl and check for the response and if it was done, you can notify the user

Comment: I mean Not all appear but one by one

Comment: Okay, So you should call the functional in set time interval and clear the notification once you shown

Comment: @Sulthan Allaudeen, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$preproses = $_POST["preproses"];
if($preproses == "preproses"){
    //mulai proses
   set_time_limit(0);

    setTimeout(function(){ buatindex() }, 3000);

   setTimeout(function(){ hitungbobot() }, 3000);

   setTimeout(function(){ panjangvektor() }, 3000);
   console.log("Completed all");
}

function buatindex() {
    code
}

function hitungbobot() {
    code
}

function panjangvektor() {
    code
}
```

Also you can `console.log` in ajax success response.

Something Like this : [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2L1jf4ep/)

Comment: Hi dude @Jaymin Noob, error code
`Parse error syntax error unexpected '}' on line 6`

Comment: line no 6 is which line?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ buatindex() }, 3000);`

Comment: Pls check I have added js fiddle link in my answer

Comment: You see I have added time after X second it will alert

Comment: I'm sorry.. my code in file **PHP** 
`<?php 
$preproses = $_POST["preproses"];
if($preproses == "preproses"){
    //mulai proses
    set_time_limit(0);
    buatindex();
    hitungbobot();
    panjangvektor();
}

function buatindex() {
    code
}

function hitungbobot() {
    code
}

function panjangvektor() {
    code
}
?>`

if I use this
`setTimeout(function(){ buatindex() }, 3000);

   setTimeout(function(){ hitungbobot() }, 3000);

   setTimeout(function(){ panjangvektor() }, 3000);`

Then the error appears
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' `

Comment: Pls check the code once I have made same function of yours

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

count your post parameter ($_POST["preproses"]) and keep into an javascript variable like var count = ""; . you can also take an hidden text variable which will be increase by 1 after every notification send. after all notification values send this hidden variable will be equal to the count variable. then you can be sure that all the notifications have been sent. Hope this will work for you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried `async: false` yet? This will stop further processing until one ajax request is complete.